# Stack Overflow calendar is broken

Tags: bug, profile-page

The daily visit calendar in Stack Overflow is not working.
`Uncaught TypeError: $cal.datepicker is not a function`

[image]

Maybe `$cal` is not initialized. I keep getting this issue for a week.

Comment: The issue still persists!